# How to merge two Maps <String, LocalDateTime> and calculate difference between values in nanoseconds

Tags: java, lambda, collections, java-8, java-stream

everyone.
I've encountered the problem while was trying to merge two maps `Map<String, LocalDateTime>`. IDE shows me compile error:

*non static method cannot be referenced from a static context*

The thing is that I need to merge them into a new one with different parameter as value, in this case, I need to calculate the difference between `LocalDateTime` of the first map and LocalDateTime of a second, therefore a result should be `Map<String, Long>`

```
Map<String, Long> result = Stream.concat(logStartTimeMap.entrySet().stream(), logEndTimeMap.entrySet().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Map.Entry::getKey,
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        (value1, value2) -> new Long(ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(value1,value2))));
```

I get error in line Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue.

And another one in line `ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(value1,value2)` as IDE thinks that value1 and value2 are of Object type instead of Temporal. And that's quite strange because previously I got that error when chose incorrect parameter type in resulting Map. But here it's ok, `ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(value1,value2)` returns Long and Map result have Long as a parameter.

Comment: What if the key does not exist in the other map? Then how can you compute the difference? Do you have the same keys in both the maps?

Comment: The error is obvious. You can't have `LocalDateTime` and `Long` difference both as the value in your map. The value and mergeFunction should comply with each other, and that condition is not true in your case.

Comment: Could you give me a hint how to make them comply with each other?

Comment: How can I give you a hint without knowing answers to above questions?

Comment: I have the same keys in both maps. The mathcing key have to be in the second map. So the situation where is no matching key is eliminated

Comment: Well, that's a valid use case. Check out my answer below.

Comment: This should do the trick `Map<String, Long> result = logStartTimeMap.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> logEndTimeMap.containsKey(e.getKey()))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        e -> ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(e.getValue(), 
            logEndTimeMap.get(e.getKey()))));`

Answer (score 1):

The way you're using `Collectors.toMap` means you're attempting to return a `Map<String, LocalDateTime>`. That's because `Map.Entry::getKey` returns a `String` and `Map.Entry::getValue` returns a `LocalDateTime`. Then in your merge function you attempt to return a `Long` which does not match the generic signature.

Instead, you can do something like the following:

```
Map<String, LocalDateTime> map1 = ...;
Map<String, LocalDateTime> map2 = ...;

Map<String, Duration> result = map1.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> Duration.between(entry.getValue(), map2.get(entry.getKey()))
));
```

The above computes a `Duration` which gives you more flexibility than just having the nanoseconds, but you can obviously change that to fit your needs:

```
Map<String, LocalDateTime> map1 = ...;
Map<String, LocalDateTime> map2 = ...;

Map<String, Long> result = map1.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> entry.getValue().until(map2.get(entry.getKey()), ChronoUnit.NANOS)
));
```

---

Note both examples above assume that `map1`'s key set is a subset of `map2`'s key set. In a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58144516/how-to-merge-two-maps-string-localdatetime-and-calculate-difference-between-v/58144916#comment102674884_58144516) you say:

> I have the same keys in both maps. The mathcing key have to be in the second map. So the situation where is no matching key is eliminated

Which means that assumption is valid. However, if that assumption becomes incorrect all you need to do is add a filter operation where you exclude any entry of `map1` whose key is not present in `map2`. Ravindra shows an example of this in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58144570/6395627).

Answer (score 0):

I see no way to do it by combining the two maps to one stream.

The mergeFunction (third parameter of `Collectors.toMap`) has to be a `BinaryOperator<U>`. That means something like (U, U) -> U. But in your code it takes two parameters of type `LocalDateTime` and returns a `Long`.

You can do it with streams like this:

```
Map<String, Long> result = logStartTimeMap.entrySet().stream()
      .map(e -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(e.getKey(), ChronoUnit.NANOS.between(e.getValue(), logEndTimeMap.get(e.getKey()))))
      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```